# Decompress gzip folder from web

Tags: python-3.x, gzip

I need to decompress a gzip-compressed folder from the internet. I have the code to download it, but am wondering how to decompress it. I have looked on the internet and have found this:

```
path = os.path.abspath('filename')
inF = gzip.open(path, 'rb')
outF = open('outfilename', 'wb')
outF.write( inF.read() )
inF.close()
outF.close()
```

However, it doesn't work for my situation because I need to decompress a folder that has many different types of files in it. This solution puts the content of the entire folder into one file, which I don't want.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "gzip-compressed folder". gzip only compresses a single file or stream. You could have a zip-compressed folder (with a file name ending in `.zip`), or you could have a tarred folder that was gzipped (with a file name ending in `.tar.gz`). What do you actually have?

Comment: I have `.tar.gz` Thanks for teaching me this.

Comment: Then you need to use [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tarfile.html).